# Running command on render gives wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run a command on render so have added the below code. It works most of the time except on a few pages I get the error: 
`wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

This is the code it is failing on:

```
  def render
    record_current_admin_timestamp
    super
  end
```

Pages that this seems to happen on are places like sign in forms and when forms fail submission. We are using unchanged devise for sign in and edit forms for admins and those are the main ones that seem to fail.

Here is the code again that is where the issue is occurring. It stops at the beginning of render and doesn't even enter the method if I put a pry or raise in there.

application_controller:

```
  def render
    record_current_admin_timestamp
    super
  end

  def record_current_admin_timestamp
    PageVisit.create(admin: current_admin, url: request.url)
  end
```

This is the type of code when it fails on the render edit. All my rspec tests that previously passed now fail when it hits the render :edit line.

```
def update
   return not_found_redirect(projects_path) unless project

   return redirect_success if project.update_attributes(params_project)

   flash[:error] = record_not_saved
   render :edit
 end
```

Any ideas would be appreciated as I am at a loss now. If you need any more info or code let me know.

Comment: Try `def render` to something else.

Comment: You should just have a `before_action` to log this admin action, overriding Rails methods is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `render :edit` in your `update` method. That means your overridden `render` needs to accept at least one argument, but `def render` does not.

In your example, it probably makes sense that you just accept all arguments and pass them to the `super` call. That would lead your `render` method to not raise errors but `super` would if it is called with an incompatible number of arguments.

```
def render(*args)
  record_current_admin_timestamp
  super
end
```